# Two content editors (gutenberg blocks) on the same page

Tags: block-editor

Can I have an extra content-editor for blocks on the same post/page?

I need to have two sections of blocks to realize the design I'm working with.

Comment: You can implement it using custom fields

Comment: Not what I've come across. If possible could you point me to where that is explained? To clarify, I need 2 sections of blocks for one page. If acf had a blocks-field that would solve it.

Comment: You could use blocks. Either use the built-in Groups block and just add 2 separate groups to the page, or build your own custom blocks if say you want to have different markup for each set. Then you could also create a post type template so every time someone adds a new post, those 2 custom blocks are automatically added for them.

Comment: Groups might do it but it's not easy enough to understand for the users we have. Any other solution that two editors will do it, thanks for your answers. I don't see how having two editors would be a problem but I can't find anything about how to achieve it.

Comment: Can you explain what you need exactly?

Comment: @Pratikb.Simform I can't really expand on that but here we go: I need two (a second or more if possible) content editor for blocks for the same page/post. I know of the blocks groups and columns but I want a second editor.

Comment: You mean 2 WYSIWYG editors on admin page?